# USB devices disconnect and are functioning intermittently

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, motherboard, troubleshooting

I was having problems with my USB devices for an hour last night, and I am unable to determine the root cause of the problem.

The two symptoms are:

1. At seemingly random times (not consistently spaced by time or caused by any detectable event) my USB devices become "detached". Windows will play the USB disconnect sound and then the reconnect sound. The devices disconnected and then reconnected.
2. My USB Keyboard will "stick" on one key for several seconds before processing any other keystroke made. The mouse also does not respond to clicks. I do not lose mouse movement or USB device connectivity. And after a moment of this several beeps will be emitted from the speakers.

Specs:

- mobo: ASUS P6X58D Premium Intel X58 Socket LGA1366 MB
- CPU: Intel Core i7-920 2.66Ghz 8M LGA1366 CPU
- RAM: Corsair Dominator 6144MB PC12800 DDR3
- GPU: EVGA GeForce GTX 470 Superclocked 1280MB DDR5 PCIe
- HDD: Hitachi 1TB Serial ATA HD 1600MHz 7200/32MB/SATA-3G
- PSU: Corsair HX1000W 1000W Modular Power Supply
- Case: Corsair Obsidian 800D Full Tower Case
- Cooling: Corsair Hydro H50 CPU Liquid Cooler

Steps I have taken to troubleshoot the problem:

1. Restarted the computer. - No change
2. Changed USB port the Hub was connected to on the CPU. - No change
3. Removed all devices from USB Hub and connected directly to CPU. - No change
4. Used a different USB keyboard both in USB Hub and directly to CPU. - No change
5. Disconnected and reconnected all cables. - No change
6. Disassembled the Tower and determined if the USB headers were firmly connected. - No change
7. Checked device manager for errors. Checked all USB devices. - Nothing flagged

After an hour of frustration trying to narrow down the problem it appeared to disappear. But I am torn between it being a motherboard problem or an OS problem.

Is there anything else I can do to narrow down the problem before a reformat and then eventually exchanging the motherboard?

Comment: Sadly, I reformatted; and the problem no longer occurs. I do wish I could have solved the problem another way.

Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You did quite a bit of hardware troubleshooting, but it doesn't look like you tried much software troubleshooting.  Before doing anything drastic, I would update all drivers for that motherboard.  If you have to, try and reinstall them and/or roll them back to see if you can elicit a change in behavior.  This is where I would start.

Comment: The system is less than about month old; and running the most up to date drivers. I did take a look at driver versions and reinstalled the latest versions of them all. The problem continued afterward.

Comment: Have you considered rolling back to a restore point?  Perhaps going back to the beginning (factory defaults) may help.  Also, perhaps install different drivers, like maybe older ones?  There could be a bug in the driver software.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what devices you have attached. This can happen if you've got a number of USB powered devices. You could be running out of juice. Check the power consumption of the USB devices (via device manager).

Comment: The USB hub I have attached is externally powered. It is a 7 port hub, with 3 connections (mouse, keyboard and external HDD that is also externally powered).